# How to display data-attribute on hover?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5xR2/

Basically have a chart which displays earnings by day.
The chart is drawn in css - based on a max width of 250px.

Trying to figure out how to show the `data-value` attribute on hover.

Comment: $(this).data('value') ?

Comment: @adeneo << yes exactly like that. But I'll fix the colors... Thanks evil genius! By the way we both share the same agenda :)

Comment: The colors was just an example, I added "mouse following" in the answer and updated the fiddle with nicer colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like

```
var chartMAX = 250
var chartMIN = 0
var highestDay = 59332
var lowestDay = 12998
var Earnings = { 1:42541, 2:23086, 3:14243, 4:36765, 5:8998, 6:998, 7:5234, 8:59332, 9:24353, 10:39911, 11:34256, 12:104, 13:12433, 14:9101 }
var chartLineBase = chartMAX / highestDay
var chartLinePxLength = chartLineBase * lowestDay +"px"

$.each( Earnings, function( i, val ) {
    var chartLineBase = chartMAX / highestDay
    var chartLinePxLength = parseInt(chartLineBase * val) +"px"
    var day = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'day',
        id     : i,
        'data-value' : '$'+val/100,
        css    : {width : chartLinePxLength},
        on     : {
            mouseenter: function(e) {
                console.log($(this).data('value'))
                $('<div />', {
                    'class' : 'tip',
                    text : $(this).data('value'),
                    css : {
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: e.pageY-22,
                        left: e.pageX+2,
                        border: '1px solid red',
                        background: 'yellow'
                    }
                }).appendTo(this);
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $('.tip', this).remove();
            },
            mousemove: function(e) {
                $('.tip', this).css({
                    top: e.pageY-22,
                    left: e.pageX+2,
                });
            }
        }
    })
    $("#earnings_chart_frame").append(day);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v5xR2/6/)

Comment: Yes now that updated style is awesome! Very nicely done! +1 for adding `mouse-following`

Comment: Console is spitting out a warning: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." Why is that?

Comment: It's an internal jQuery issue, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

Without using jQuery you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/v5xR2/2/

[image]

That's using this CSS, plus adding a `position:relative;` to `.day`.

```
day:hover {
  background-color: red;  
}

.day:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-value);
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: black;
    background-color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 100%;
    z-index:10;
    border:1px black solid;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #ccc;
}
```

The main thing here is generated content. Can I use (http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent) shows this works in IE8 and up.

Comment: Not sure, you might want to add `.day:focus:after` as well for that. Make sure you test!

Answer (score 1):

The most basic answer is to use the `title` attribute which in most browsers will present a tooltip on hover:

```
"...title=\"$" + val/100 + "\""
```

For styling and more advanced options, I'd recommend using [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) (which you just declare at the top of your page, and it still uses the title attributes - so very easy to implement).

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v5xR2/1/

Answer (score 0):

To support tooltips compatible with HTML5 which also look nice (when possible), use CSS to style all `title` attributes.

Notes:

- Some elements (`svg`) do not support tooltips
- Some elements (`img`, `input`, etc.) respect the default tooltip over the styled one
- pseudo elements (`::before`, `::after`) inherit parent element properties which may need to be overridden to look right for a tooltip

```css
:root {
  /* variables which can be replaced with your own settings */
  --c: 130;
  --c-light: hsla(var(--c), 15%, 95%, 1);
  --c-dark: hsla(var(--c), 15%, 15%, 1);
  --bs: 1px 1px 3px 0px var(--c-dark);
}

*[title] {
  /* required */
  position: relative;
  /* decorative */
  cursor: help;
}

*[title]:hover::after {
  /* required */
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--c-light);
  height: fit-content;
  width: max-content;
  z-index: 1;
  /* decorative */
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  box-shadow: var(--bs);
  inset: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  max-width: 20em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 title="This is a header">About Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p title="This is a paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" title="This is an image" />
  <form>
    <label for="text_1" title="This is a form label">Text Input</label>
    <input type="text" id="text_1" title="This is a form input" />
  </form>
  <div title="This is a div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <span title="This is a span">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
</div>
```